# Confirm AD Computer description change in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to confirm a Active Directory computer description change was successful in PowerShell and I'm stuck. I'm using the Set-ADComputer cmdlet with the PassThru parameter. According to the documentation PassThru is supposed to return the object that you just modified. My script is similar to this,

```
$result = Set-ADComputer $CompName -Description $Description -Credential $cred -PassThru
if ($result.Description -ne $Description){
   #Description didn't change so do something
}
```

I'd like to test the description of the result to confirm that the change occurred but the object I get back doesn't have a description property. If I do a $result.PropertyNames it only returns nine properties,

DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, UserPrincipalName

I successfully get back an object in $result with the name property set the computer I'm changing and if I look in ADUC I can see the description was changed but I want a confirmation of this in my script. Where's the description property?

Comment: This is because `-PassThru` is most likely returning the _ADComputer_ default properties, it doesn't "update" the object that was passed as parameter. You can rest assure that, if the cmdlet didn't throw, the AD Object was modified. But if you want to be sure about this, you should query the AD Object one more time with `Get-ADComputer ... -Properties Description`.

Comment: in addition to what SantiagoSquarzon mentioned, you likely need to usee the `-Server` parameter for both CD calls. otherwise you may end up sending the change to ServerOne and then reading from ServerSeventyOne. [*grin*] replication delays can make verifying a change iffy unless you make it a point to always deal with the exact same AD server.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey excellent point too!